# fill html form when select value from mysql table using drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, pdo

I've table calles **products_tbl**

```
+-----+------------+----------------+-------+------+-----------+
|pr_id|product_name|product_category|Price1 |Price2|product_img|
+-----+------------+----------------+-------+------+-----------+
|1    |Apple       |fruits          |12     |15    |aimg.jpg   |
|2    |Orange      |fruits          |10     |11    |orimg.jpg  |
|3    |Iphone X    |Electronics     |900    |1025  |iphimg.jpg |
|4    |FJ-Eye Lens |Accessories     |20     |25    |fjimg.jpg  |
+-----+------------+----------------+-------+------+-----------+
```

I've grab **product_name** from table and put it in **Select Option** and when user choose value from select option it display it image and put it in img tag (this worked perfect).

I want when user select some product name from select option it displayed the price1 and price2 in 2 text input as the same as the image

**products.php**

```
$productQ = "SELECT * FROM products_tbl ORDER BY product_category ASC";
try { 
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($productQ); 
    $stmt2->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run membersQ: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$produtsrows = $stmt2->fetchAll();

echo"<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' required>
        <option selected disabled>Choose</option>";
    $category = "";
    foreach($produtsrows as $prow): 
        if ($category != $prow['product_category']) {
            if ($category != "") {
                echo "</optgroup>";
            }
            $category = $prow['product_category'];
            echo "<optgroup label=".$prow['product_name'].">";
        }
        echo"   <option value='imgs/".$prow['product_img']."'>".$prow['product_name']."</option>";
    endforeach;
    echo "</optgroup>
</select>
<input type='text' name='p1' id='p1' value=''>
<input type='text' name='p1' id='p2' value=''>

<img id='image' src='' alt=''>";
```

and **JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $( '#dropdown' ).change(function(){
        $( '#image' ).attr( 'src', $( this ).val() + '' );
        $( '#p1' ).attr( 'value', $( this ).val() + '' );
        $( '#p2' ).attr( 'value', $( this ).val() + '' );
    })

});

</script>
```

**when I select any value from select option it display the name of the image in the textbox rather than price1 and price2**

**how can I display the price1 and price2 rather than image name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply new attribute in order to get more then one value from drop down list.

> Solution :
>
> Step 1 : Add `data-price1='.$prow['Price1'].'` and `data-price2='.$prow['Price2'].'`
>
> Step 2 : Use jquery `attr` to get `data-price*` values

Example :

.php File :

```
$productQ = "SELECT * FROM products_tbl ORDER BY product_category ASC";
try { 
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($productQ); 
    $stmt2->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run membersQ: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$produtsrows = $stmt2->fetchAll();

echo"<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' required>
        <option selected disabled>Choose</option>";
    $category = "";
    foreach($produtsrows as $prow): 
        if ($category != $prow['product_category']) {
            if ($category != "") {
                echo "</optgroup>";
            }
            $category = $prow['product_category'];
            echo "<optgroup label=".$prow['product_name'].">";
        }
        echo"   <option value='imgs/".$prow['product_img']."' data-price1='.$prow['Price1'].' data-price2='.$prow['Price2'].'>".$prow['product_name']."</option>";
    endforeach;
    echo "</optgroup>
</select>
<input type='text' name='p1' id='p1' value=''>
<input type='text' name='p1' id='p2' value=''>

<img id='image' src='' alt=''>";
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $( '#dropdown' ).change(function(){
        $('#image').attr( 'src', $( this ).val() + '' );
        $('#p1').attr( 'value', $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price1'));
        $('#p2').attr( 'value', $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price2'));
    })
});
```

Check below HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        $('#p1').attr('value', $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price1'));
        $('#p2').attr('value', $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price2'));
    })
});//jq
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Change list : 
<select id="dropdown">
    <option data-price1="12" data-price2="15">Apple</option>
    <option data-price1="10" data-price2="11">Orange</option>
    <option data-price1="900" data-price2="1025">Iphone X</option>
    <option data-price1="20" data-price2="25">FJ-Eye Lens</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 1 : <input type="text" id="p1" />
<br />
Price 2 : <input type="text" id="p2" />
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I think this refers to the dropdown & you bind the data-price & data-price2 to option. Maybe you need to check the option: selected attribute value.

Comment: it return `undefined` in the 2 textbox

Comment: I think you need something $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price1''));

Comment: @HaydeerHussien, applied HTML working code above, please check

Comment: Dear @saAction the HTML example worked perfectly, but when I'm trying it to my code its not showing any results

Comment: @HaydeerHussien, Make sure that the value is coming from php side, use developer tool to inspect HTML code and check both attribute has value inside.

Comment: @saAction value is coming from php side because it already worked in image tag (when I change any value from select option it display its own image depending on `<option value=' imgs/".$prow['product_img']." '>`  

thats worked perfectly (if i use `$('#p1').attr( 'value', $( this ).val() + '' );` and `$('#p2').attr( 'value', $( this ).val() + '' );` its display the image name in these two fields

Comment: @saAction I've edit my code and i remove the `<optgroup>` tags and its worked perfectly, this means I can't group items in their categories

Comment: Thanks m8. This worked for me. Maybe as an addendum you can add that people should ensure they import Jquery and add .jQuery(); at the end of the function. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

```
Bind the attribute in option and change the script..

<select id="slct" onchange="dropdownhange(this)">
<option value="1" data-cust="a"> 1 </option>
<option value="2" data-cust="b"> 2 </option>
<option value="3" data-cust="c"> 3 </option>
</select>

function dropdownhange(obj){
  console.log($(obj).val());
  console.log($(obj).children('option:selected').attr('data-cust'));
}
```

https://codepen.io/pixel-lab/pen/zJdqvv?editors=1111

Comment: its working on console ? how about display it in the textbox ?

Comment: something like :  $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        $('#p1').val($(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price1'));
        $('#p2').val($(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-price2'));
    })